# Semantic ui search module

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui search module, the content will be a remote JSON file, can make it work but no matter what i typed whether its found or not, i will show up the list from the JSON file.

**script**

```
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
    apiSettings: {
      url: 'http://localhost/api/materialMaster.json'
    },
    fields: {
      results : 'data',
      title : 'matcode'
    },
    minCharacters : 2
  })
;
```

**JSON file format is**

```
{"data":[{"matcode":"0A66244S1"},{"matcode":"200GD0S100150CM"}]}
```

Comment: i dont know what is the behavior in this search feature but if I search for the text "test" here `http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html` (Local Search section), it will give wrong results :)

Comment: I figured it out. If full-text search feature is on it will search for matching text inside. Try to disable full text search using the ff property : `searchFullText: false`

Comment: at least in their example, still can filter some of them, while mine will show the same result no matter what i type. what is ff? is it firefox?

Comment: can you post a fiddle so I can check?

Comment: where should i upload the JSON file?

Comment: try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n3exrk83/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105522/discussion-between-euphoriagrogi-and-joseph-goh).

Comment: when i check your fiddle it is not displaying all the entries

Comment: `https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1847` check the developer comment. Searching will only work for local not for remote

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ypu4wcko/

Comment: weird, in their documentation, it said it can search a custom API. http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/usage

Comment: yah but the results from the API should be the filtered one based on the given searchtext in front end, so the data you returned back from the server is expected to be filtered already.

Comment: so any idea how to modified the code to be able to search through the JSON file? or maybe we can change the api?

Comment: change your api to filter the result based on the passed query string values :) aja!

Comment: ok, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

See if this can help. I had this same problem and I solved using this instructions.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32937262/5381965